# Transferring from Beautiful Soup to LXML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

If I have code in BS4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_tree = BeautifulSoup('A lot of HTML here', 'html.parser')
shopping_bag_body = html_tree.find('table', attrs={'id': 'shoppingBag'}).find('tbody')
all_products = shopping_bag_body.find_all('tr')
product_price = product.find('td', attrs={'class': 'column-5'}).find('span', attrs={'class': 'price'})
```

How to use LXML xpath instead in such cases?

Comment: Why do you want to transfer from bsoup to lxml?

Comment: @VincentBeltman it`s a quick task from customer